# iconv with codepage 437 fails

Tags: php, iconv

I'm running the php function iconv on two different but very similar server installations:

```
iconv("UTF-8", "CP437//IGNORE", 'test');
```

On the first server (php v7.4.7) it works OK. The second (php v7.1.125) returns 'Wrong charset, conversion from `UTF-8' to` CP437//IGNORE' is not allowed'. If I change CP437 to ASCII it works OK.

I listed the character sets with the command iconv -l. I can see CP437 listed on both servers.

Any idea how to fix this problem on the second server?

Comment: Try inspecting the current locale to see if they are the same by `var_dump(setlocale(0))`. The zero is used to not change anything, only return

Comment: I get identical results on both:`var_dump(setlocale(LC_ALL, 0));` gives "LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=C;LC_COLLATE=C;LC_MONETARY=C;LC_MESSAGES=C;LC_PAPER=C;LC_NAME=C;LC_ADDRESS=C;LC_TELEPHONE=C;LC_MEASUREMENT=C;LC_IDENTIFICATION=C"